# What are possible ways to migrate SQL Server DB to PostgreSQL DB?

Tags: postgresql, migration

Currently I am assigned to complete the task of migrating several small to large databases (from 10GB to 200GB) from `SQL Server` to `PostgreSQL` RDBMS.

I would like to ask the community to share experience of migration.

1. Are there free ways to migrate? I am aware of creating `SSIS` solution
   but it seems that there I have to migrate table by table
2. Which tool have you successfully used to complete such tasks?

Thank you

Comment: Convert your DDL scripts from SQL Server to Postgres. Export the data to flat files. Import them in Postgres using `copy`

Comment: You can try this: http://dalibo.github.io/sqlserver2pgsql/

Comment: If source have stored procedures of functions best possible way is to migrate that parts manually. Regex replaces or such automatic replacing methods just doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Foreign Data Wrapper and [tds_fdw](https://github.com/tds-fdw/tds_fdw)

Or you can try [pgloader](https://pgloader.io/).

Both work perfectly, are easy to set up and are packaged on any serious Linux distributions.